# how to execute JUnit test in Maven?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, junit

I have created webdriver test for project and it works fine.
Now I have added testpackage to Maven project and did some pom.xml changes then try to execute 1 test and i have following error

> Class not found com.abc.xyz.con.TestExpressMode
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.abc.xyz.con.TestExpressMode   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Now i did so much google and not able to fix this problem.
i have 1.8 jdk and developers have 1.6 i hope this is not a issue or?

Thanks

Comment: Could be, but I think the real problem is a .class files that's missing from the project.  What is that TestExpressMode thingy?  Is that an Eclipse class?  Try running the test lifecycle outside of Eclipse on a command line.

Comment: its just  a junit test

Comment: which kind of class is missing? and how i can add and where?

Comment: @Pooja, can you share your directory structure. May be an image is also fine.

Comment: also, if i build project Run as-->Maven than getting error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project SpringFileUpload: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]

Comment: when i check tools.jar is there or not on location  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\ib\tools.jar ->  is available but i am not able to understand followinf path .C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_102\..\lib\tools.jar -> \..\before lib

Comment: @RITZXAVI structure is very simple src\test\java:package:.java files (these are test )

Comment: You are trying to use the JRE to compile. You need to use the JDK and set JAVA_HOME to it. If you're trying to run this from within Eclipse, add the JDK to eclipse's Java runtimes.

Comment: JAVA_HOME mean envirnment variable ? if yes than i have this already. also i have change from jre to jdk and execute test again some following errors appears now : .m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\jetty-repacked\7.6.1\jetty-repacked-7.6.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project SpringFileUpload: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.2\httpmime-4.5.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: error: error reading C:\Users\.m2\repository\mx4j\mx4j-tools\3.0.1\mx4j-tools-3.0.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\servlet-api-2.5\6.1.9\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.9.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: error: error reading C:\Users\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.1.0\jna-4.1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Take a look at a post that i answered before on the same matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675845/classnotfoundexception-for-included-dependency/39687000#39687000