# Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am new to spring framework. I am trying to set up Java EE web application using Spring 4 and Hibernate 5. But I am running into following error while running the app on a server. I have spend whole day stuck at this problem. Please help me find the problem. Also, I have general difficulty in understanding the configuration of a `Java + Spring + Hibernate` project. Is there any good materials that explain how to set up bean, etc.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:974)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:752)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
```

I have pasted below my maven properties section:

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <xml-api-version>1.4.01</xml-api-version>
        <hibernate-version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>softsecbanking</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.group6.*"/>

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>  
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value> 
        </property>
  </bean>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  </beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/bankschema</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping class="org.group6.model.Login"/>
        <mapping class="org.group6.model.Profile"/>
        <mapping class="org.group6.model.Account"/>
        <mapping class="org.group6.model.CreditCard"/>
        <mapping class="org.group6.model.TransactionRequest"/>
        <!-- <mapping resource="login.hbm.xml"/> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have `spring-orm` in your dependencies? If yes, which Version?

Comment: @Jens:spring-orm version I am using 4.2.1.RELEASE.

Comment: This sould contain the class. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Add youyr maven pom instead of a snippet... RUn `mvn dependency:tree` to see what your dependencies and versions are instead of thinking you are using 4.2.x. Also which server are you deploying to?

Comment: I already answered this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675845/classnotfoundexception-for-included-dependency/39687000#39687000

Answer (score 2):

in your `<session-factory>` of **hibernate.cfg.xml** file,

use `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>`

in place of `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>`

and add following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
```

and your bean for dispatcher-servlet.xml will be like,

```
<bean id="mysessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  

    <!-- following bean is required only in case of using hbm.xml file, not needed in case of using annotations -->

    <!-- <property name="mappingResources">  
    <list>  
    <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
    </list>  
    </property> -->  



    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```